# RabbitMQ design advice: Routing DLX message back to originating publisher

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

---

**EDIT:** The underlying requirement is that I have multiple web-service server processes receiving requests from web-service clients, performing some processing (what I want to use a worker queue for), and then returning the result back to to the respective client. However I want to be able to wait for a consumer of this queue to pick up a published request, **within a timeout**. If this timeout expires, then I want the original webservice process to receive a notification of this so it can feed back to the client.

---

- I have multiple publishers publishing messages to the same exchange
- There are multiple consumers on this exchange consuming from the same queue, i.e. 'task-queues'

I'm trying to implement a sort of 'Publish TTL', whereby the **originating publisher** (only) is notified if a message is dead-lettered. (I want the publisher to know if a message is not consumed within a certain timeout).

I have a solution as follows:

- When publishing messages, each publisher uses a routing key containing a unique (per publisher) Process-ID, e.g. '***thekey.pid3***' for publisher 3
- Consumers each consume from the same queue, that is bound to the exchange using the routing key '***thekey.#***'
- I'm not explicitly specifying any routing-key for the DLX when publishers declare the queue -- only the '**x-dead-letter-exchange**'. This means that if a message is deadlettered, then the original routing-key (i.e. '***thekey.pid3***') will carry through to the DLX.
- Each publisher binds it's own new consumer queue to the DLX using it's specific routing key, e.g. '***thekey.pid3***'

So this resolves my requirement, as only the publisher that published the message will have the DLX message routed to it.

This, however, seems a little convoluted -- and inefficient, as the wildcard routing occurs for ALL messages (except those dead-lettered -- which shouldn't *normally* be happening).

This must be a common requirement -- is my solution advisable? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or am I on the right track?

Here's a diagram showing my design:

**EDIT:** *In the below diagram, the DLX should actually be connected to the queue, not the Exchange!*
[image: DLX back to originating publisher]

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on your needs, SO may not be the best choice for discussions, try [RabbitMQ official user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users)

Comment: Thanks Zaq. I've edited the question with a brief overview of the underlying BL requirement in case that clarifies things. However I'll post this on the Rabbit group too.

Comment: RabbitMQ mailing list discussion about this question is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/xVsSV5R1sk8/DxpN-sbYhBIJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so it turns out the solution is quite valid. There may be a *small* latency hit when using a wildcard binding key and topic exchange, but probably nothing to really concern oneself about.

One comment from the mailing list was that because this is an RPC-based system, each Publisher **already** has a unique response-queue defined, so one could bind that queue to the DLX (rather than creating a new, unique-queue-per-publisher), and thereby get both 'valid' responses and dead-lettered messages delivered to the same queue.

In my case, I wanted to make wrap this 'Publish TTL' functionality in a generic publisher, so referring to the response-queue didn't make sense -- although my solution may be slightly less efficient, as there is one more round-trip in the event of a dead-letter.

If you're interested in the mechanism the guys at Rabbit use for topic routing, you can check out:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/09/14/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-1/
http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/03/28/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-2/